# Variable "Rs.Temp" not found

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting error while executing a sql query in Alpha Anywhere Query (AlphaADO) section.

[image]

The code i'm executing is attached.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
tbl_wo_kitting.wo_kitting_id, 
tbl_wo_kitting.level_no, 
tbl_wo_kitting.line_no_parent, 
tbl_wo_kitting.line_no AS kitting_line_no, 
tbl_wo_kitting.production_type, 
tbl_wo_kitting.quantity AS kitting_quantity, 
tbl_wo_kitting.release_to_wr, 
tbl_wo_kitting.mpn, 

m_product.m_product_id, 
m_product.value, 
m_product.name, 
m_product.storelocator, 

tbl_wo_project.wo_project_id, 
tbl_wo_project.line_no AS project_line_no, 
tbl_wo_project.quantity AS project_quantity, 

m_transaction_moveqty_v.qtyonhand AS qtyonhand, 

tbl_work_order.work_order_id, 
tbl_work_order.reference_key, 

case 
when tbl_wo_kitting.level_no,  = 'P+'
then '0'
else tbl_wo_kitting.level_no, 
end as linenumber,

case 
when tbl_wo_kitting.line_no_parent = 'PT+'
then '0'
else tbl_wo_kitting.line_no_parent
end as linenoparent


FROM (tbl_wo_kitting tbl_wo_kitting

     INNER JOIN (m_product m_product
         INNER JOIN m_transaction_moveqty_v m_transaction_moveqty_v
             ON  m_product.m_product_id = m_transaction_moveqty_v.m_product_id )
         ON  tbl_wo_kitting.m_product_id = m_product.m_product_id 

     INNER JOIN (tbl_wo_project tbl_wo_project
         INNER JOIN tbl_work_order tbl_work_order
             ON  tbl_wo_project.work_order_id = tbl_work_order.work_order_id )
         ON  tbl_wo_kitting.wo_project_id = tbl_wo_project.wo_project_id )) AS TABLE1

ORDER BY tbl_wo_kitting.level_no, (string_to_array(linenoparent, '.'))::int[],(string_to_array(linenumber, '.'))::int[]
```

Any idea? This is selecting from PostgreSQL.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't see `Rs.Temp` anywhere in the query.  Is there additional code anywhere?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres. This seems to be a problem with that "SQL Genie" thing

Comment: Ah, picking past the screenshot, the actual error message is shown in text in the background: "line 2:2 Unexpected Token: SELECT". The "Alpha Anywhere" dialogue on top is a red herring, and just the application having awful error handling, I think.